# Selecting variable_of_tablename.* from tablename gives 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT sur.* FROM table_name
```

Whenever I run this code in SQLDeveloper it it gives me the error

ORA-00904: "SUR": invalid identifier

904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

I'm not sure how to fix this and haven't been able to find anything online. The reason I have to use this format is because it follows a format already being implemented by previous developers and I have to adhere to that standard.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: You need to define the table alias in the `from` clause:  `from table_name sur`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT sur.* FROM table_name sur;
```

You have used a sur alias for referring all the columns of the table table_name but before you can use that you need to give table table_name an alias like sur

However the below query will work fine as you are using the actual table name instead of a different alias name.

```
select table_name.* from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you ask to list columns from table "SUR" but since no such table exists in "from" clause, Oracle raises this error.

There are 2 options here:

1. Give an alias (a second name) to any of the table in from clause
   For eg:

   select sur.* from tablename1 sur, tablename2 foo where sur.col1=foo.col1
2. Use table name itself rather than using column alias "SUR"
   For eg:

   select tablename1.* from tablename1, tablename2 where tablename1.col1=tablename2.col1

Refer: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/alias.php